# Optimize conditional expression inside if statement

Tags: javascript

I have below piece of conditional block in Javascript. I optimized it to the level possible by me, but I feel that it can still be more optimized.

Can someone please suggest a better way to write below code.

```
if(flag) {
  this.flag = flag; /* some assignment*/
  oldSearchType = newSearchType ? newSearchType : oldSearchType; /*Any better way to write this?*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the second part like this:

```
oldSearchType = newSearchType || oldSearchType;
```

which most of us would find clearer. The global `if(flag) {` condition is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I find the most obvious solution also the most clear:

```
if (newSearchType) {
    oldSearchType = newSearchType;
}
```